# Like xsl:value-of, but with a space or dot at element boundaries

Tags: xslt

I'll bet there is a clever, terse way to do this.

```
<xsl:call-template name="item">
  <xsl:with-param name="name" ><xsl:value-of select="name()" /></xsl:with-param>
  <xsl:with-param name="value"><xsl:value-of select="."      /></xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

See the `xsl:value-of select="."` Usually all is well. But sometimes, the current node will have children and the text all runs together when I'd like some break:

```
The Right Stuff<line/>Tom Wolfe
```

or

```
<title>The Right Stuff</title><author>Tom Wolfe</author>
```

In these cases, I'd like a space or dot or something between "Stuff" and "Tom".

How could I say `xsl:value-of select="." but add a space instead of running node contents together`?

Comment: First of all, you are sending 2 values as parameter to a named template. I think you can do away with the item node itself and extract the node name and containing text value in the called template.

Comment: Yes, that's an artifact of the example, though. The call is used in several places and the name and value parameters are not always functions of the current node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, never write this:

```
<xsl:with-param name="name" ><xsl:value-of select="name()" /></xsl:with-param>
```

when you could write this:

```
<xsl:with-param name="name" select="name()" />
```

It's not only verbose, its also grossly inefficient to construct a temporary tree in memory when you only need a simple string. Sadly, this mistake seems to be becoming ever more common.

xsl:value-of, when given an element, extracts the string value of the element, which is the concatenation of the text nodes. This is convenient when people are using the common and familiar markup design for mixed content where stripping all the tags leaves you with human-readable content. If the XML hasn't been designed to use this convention, then this rule for the string value is less useful (which is why, in schema-aware XPath, you aren't allowed to get the string value of an element unless it is defined with simple content or mixed content).

In your case I would suggest passing the element node as a parameter, rather than its string value, and in the called template using apply-templates to process the content of the element node.

Comment: @Dr. Kay: Oh-oh. Can you add just another sentence or two about what the inefficiency is and what should be avoided? I wouldn't have expected much difference. -- Thanks!

Comment: When xsl:variable or other variable binding elements contain a sequence constructor and no "as" attribute, they are defined to contsruct a new document node (or in XSLT 1.0, a result tree fragment). That's a very heavyweight data structure compared with a simple string, number, or node reference. Using the select attribute is always best if you don't need to build a new tree. The optimizer can sometimes convert it for you automatically, but only with some complex data flow analysis looking at exactly how the variable is used.

Comment: As for the cost, I once tripled the speed of a stylesheet by fixing this problem wherever it occurred.

Comment: @Dr. Kay: ...and xsl:value-of is such a variable-binding element. Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When we use `<xsl:value-of select="."/>` then it puts the value of the context node as well as all the child nodes. I don't think we can simply add a "." or "space" between the text values.

However, we can implement it in such a way that we iterate over such child nodes and therby get a chance to add a "." or "space".

Let's assume your XML looks like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
     <item>
        <title>The Right Stuff</title><author>Tom Wolfe</author>
     </item>
</root>
```

Then, you can use the following XSL to put a "." after the values of child nodes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="xml" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="Item">
            <xsl:with-param name="name" select="name()"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="value" select="//item[1]"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="Item">
        <xsl:param name="name" />
        <xsl:param name="value" />
        <xsl:for-each select="$value/*">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>.
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Write this whenever you need spaces:

```
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
```